"You attempted to use a Firebase module that's not installed natively on your project by calling firebase.app()." after upgrading React Native
ERROR  Error: You attempted to use a Firebase module that's not installed natively on your project by calling firebase.app().
Ensure you have installed the npm package '@react-native-firebase/app', have imported it in your project, and have rebuilt your native application.
This error is located at:
in app
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in ChildrenWrapper (created by Root)
in _default (created by Root)
in Root (created by AppContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in AppContainer
in Integrity(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
After upgrading React Native from 0.68.4 to 0.73.4, I reinstalled Firebase using Yarn.
I double-checked my Firebase setup in MainApplication.java to ensure the Firebase app module was correctly imported.
I also verified that my Firebase initialization code (firebase.app()) was correctly implemented, and this setup worked perfectly before the upgrade.
I expected the Firebase module to initialize and work as it did before the React Native version upgrade, with no native module errors. I was hoping that after the upgrade, Firebase would continue to integrate smoothly into my project without any issues.

I got this error after upgrading the react-native version to 0.68.4 to 0.73.4

are you using expo go?

No , i am using react native cli

@SourabhSudheer  Even though all the packages are installed and the setup seems fine, I still don't understand what the exact problem is.

I believe you are using old firebase syntax. Like V8 would use firebase.app(). In V9+ (latest 10) you would import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app"; and do const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);. I hope this helps. You can also ask an AI to give you more details on V8 vs V9 as my answer might be confusing.

Thanks for your help, but I will do this, which still shows the same error.
